# Incrementing cell reference in a formula with varying Offsets - Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create an excel macro which involves copying data between two workbooks (say wb1 and wb2).

In wb2 I want to assign a certain formula to a series of cells of a specific column. So the cell of wb1 referenced in the formula has to be incremented.

```
F1(wb2) = COUNTIF(range in wb1,contidion)*A1(wb1)*B1(wb1)
F5(wb2) = COUNTIF(range in wb1,condition)*A2(wb1)*B2(wb1)
.
.
.
F50(wb2)= COUNTIF(range in wb1,condition)*A10(wb1)*B10(wb1)
```

How can I acheieve this using excel Macros ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple matter composing the string to build the formula for each cell.  The code below will build these formulas in wb2:

```
F5: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A1*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B1
F10: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A2*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B2
F15: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A3*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B3
F20: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A4*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B4
F25: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A5*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B5
F30: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A6*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B6
F35: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A7*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B7
F40: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A8*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B8
F45: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A9*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B9
F50: =COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,">5")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A10*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B10
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub copy_cells()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim row As Integer
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("book1.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("book2.xlsm")
 
    For row = 1 To 10
        wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(row * 5, "F").Formula = "=COUNTIF([Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!D1:D25,"">5"")*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!A" & row & "*[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!B" & row
    Next
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Copying the values from one workbook with another is not too difficult, but I'm unclear why you at indicating that the destination cells (e.g. F5 on wb2) already have values.  If you want to copy values to those destination cells, it will replace the data already there.  Here is a macro to do the copying.  This code assumes that book1 and book2 are already open.  The code copies data from the first worksheet in book1 and puts it in the first sheet of book2.

```
Sub copy_cells()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim row As Integer
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("book1.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("book2.xlsm")
 
    For row = 1 To 10
        wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(row * 5, "F").Value = wb1.Worksheets(1).Cells(row, "D").Value
    Next
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. What I mean by pre-existing default values which are not important and can be replaced....

But the actul problem is I just cant directly assign the values like above because the cell in wb2 is calculated based on few cell from wb1..I ll try to be more precise with my question this time. I will make the edit in my original post.

Comment: @SherwinR, do you want to put a formula in F5 of wb2?   When you say you want to copy from D1 of wb1 to F5 of wb2, It seems that you want replace what is in F5 with what is in D1, so its prior content seems irrelevant.  This is what you need to make clear.

Comment: From your questions, you say that F5 has a formula that references D1 but your example ("D1(wb1) = x*y*F5(wb2)") seems to indicated that D1 has a formula that references F5

Comment: Yea exactly..pls ignore my previous Example...The cell names are just examples in each case..So it has no connection to my previous Post..Just take the current example into consideration